# How can I convert an array of NSNumbers to an array of Ints?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsnumber

How to get Int value from NSNumber in Swift? Or convert array of NSNumber to Array of Int values?

I have a list of NSNumber

```
let array1:[NSNumber]
```

I want a list of Int values from this array

```
let array2:[Int] = Convert array1
```

Comment: What is the expected result if the input is  something like `[1, 2.5, 3]`?

Comment: `let array2: [Int] = array1.map { $0.intValue }`

Comment: Why do you use `NSNumber` at all?

Comment: I am getting response from rest API which is in Number format.

Comment: Doesn’t a rest api deliver json?

Comment: *I am getting response from rest API which is in Number format.* Usually an API sends something in a **string** format (even numbers), and no API on earth sends specific Objective-C `NSNumber` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is the expected result if there is non integer elements in your collection.

```
let array1: [NSNumber] = [1, 2.5, 3]
```

If you want to keep the collection only if all elements are integers

```
let array2 = array1 as? [Int] ?? []           //  [] all or nothing
```

If you want to get only the integers from the collection

```
let array3 = array1.compactMap { $0 as? Int } //  [1, 3] only integers
```

If you want the whole value of all elements

```
let array4 = array1.map(\.intValue)           //  [1, 2, 3] whole values
```

Comment: Thanks Leo, I was expecting to get 1 and 3 and I got it fixed with
let array2 =  array1.compactMap(Int.init)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue with one line of code:

```
  let array1 : [NSNumber] = [1, 2.5, 3]

  let array2 =  array1.compactMap {Int(truncating: $0)}

  let array3 =  array1.compactMap(Int.init)
```

it returns an array of Int values.

```
Result of array2 = [1,2,3]
Result of array3 = [1,3]
```